# Blurred pane over video iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7

My app plays video.

I want to put a blurred pane over the video like the one I get by swiping from the top.[image]

Note there is video playing "behind" the pane.

How can I accomplish this in iOS 7 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `LFGlassView`. Add it as a subview over whatever content you want blurred: https://github.com/radi/LiveFrost/

Comment: it does not blurs AVPlayer video while playing.

Comment: @EvgenyKarkan Use iOS 8's visual effects class.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but my project still supports iOS 7.